# How to change the height and width of a button in iOS app using Swift 4.0 which is developed using Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, xcode9, swift4

I am completely new to iOS development and I am supposed to fix some bugs in an iOS app which is made using Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8 and it works almost fine. But when I open it with Xcode 9 and Swift 4.0 it shows some buttons way different that they were before.

Here is the source code for one of those buttons.

```
let button: UIButton = UIButton.init(type: UIButtonType.custom)
    //set image for button
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "menu.png"), for: UIControlState())
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 23)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.shareButtonPressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

this code is inside the ViewDidLoad method. My problem is when I remove,

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "menu.png"), for: UIControlState())
```

it disappears the button but when I change the height and the width from,

```
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 23)
```

it changes nothing.
My problem is how can I fix this bug. Any suggestion, answer is highly appreciated and if the given details are not enough, please mention. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Beginning with iOS 11, views added to toolbars using `UIBarButtonItem` using `UIBarButtonItem(customView:)` are now laid out using auto layout. You should add sizing constraints on your `button`. For example:

```
button.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(30.0).isActive = true
button.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(23.0).isActive = true
```

Otherwise, auto layout will use the intrinsic content size of your header view which is likely not what you expect.

For more information see the WWDC 2017 session [Updating your app for iOS 11](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/204/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works as this

`if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }`

Comment: Yes. Anchors were introduced with iOS 9. If you are targeting below that, you need the `#available` but as mentioned constraint sizing will only be applied  on iOS 11 and up.

Answer (score 11):

swift 4:

```
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0).isActive = true
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
```

Comment: constraintEqualToConstant changed to 'constraint(equalToConstant: '.  btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0).isActive = true

Answer (score 0):

You can customize width and height of button using storyboard in Xcode. Just select your button and open this window.
[image: Constraint Layout]

After that just add the height constraints.